# Why is my JsonProvider causing an exception when parsing a file?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

**I receive the following exception message when using a JsonProvider:**

> > System.Exception: Invalid JSON starting at character 0, snippet =
>
> ---
>
> https://fac
>
> ---
>
> json =
>
> ---
>
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json
>
> ---

**My code is the following:**

```
open FSharp.Data

type MovieProvider = JsonProvider<"https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json">

let result = MovieProvider.Parse "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"
```

**The exception is thrown when executing this line:**

```
let result = MovieProvider.Parse "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"
```

NOTE:

I am referencing the this [documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html).

Comment: You're trying to parse a URL as JSON. You probably want `MovieProvider.Load`...

Comment: Duh... I feel so silly for asking. Thx!

Comment: @GuyCoder done.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to parse a URL as JSON. You probably want `MovieProvider.Load`.